# How do i remove email validation in Magento 1.8 Admin area

Tags: magento, email-validation

I'm having problems validating my email address through admin. I tried everything from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317122/how-do-i-remove-email-validation-in-magento-1-7-admin-area)

Yet I'm still having trouble. I've been at this for 4 days and still not working. Anyone that knows please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you removed the class "validate-email" from the input field? You can check this by inspecting html. In Chrome this can be done by pressing `cmd(ctrl)+shift+c`.

For Firefox try this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: Sorry kind of a newbie. What file do I have to edit to remove the validate-email from admin area?